# Declaring this in a Typescript Function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use an example to understand a [section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) in TS documentation.

Here's the code.

```js
class User {
    id: number;
    admin: boolean;

    constructor(id: number, admin: boolean) {
        this.id = id;
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    becomeAdmin() {
        this.admin = true;
    }
}

interface DB {
    filterUsers(filter: (this: User) => boolean): User[];
}

function getDB(): DB {
    return {
        filterUsers: function(filter: (this: User) => boolean) {
            const users = [new User(1, false), new User(2, true)];
            return users.filter(filter);
        }
    }
}

const db = getDB();
const admins = db.filterUsers(function(this: User) {
    return this.admin;
});

console.log(admins);
```

I'm expecting `[{id: 2, admin: true}]` to be printed. But `this` being `undefined` is causing error.

Why is this error happening and how do I modify `getDB()` function to resolve this problem?

[Link to Typescript Playground to run the code above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBYIqHDNDxkLyIeB9BjA9g0L5uMzMdgMZiQfiwaDqRJM+B6EReABEAFFVgxEAt9OKktjxeAHKgAOTCABykAk4qCKgA8l8yO9BLytJAjqhHApXNI8KAnPSdMMsPoUAhENDhJc2RIGdERAYONiFkxWBweEFFPyGIJhPdzdiAN6KEolCjcfL9diIaTfADc6YzDG4iAyOeB8BanGLJZKCE4glQZHYsHQZAAFFmc5w8wWyBdy5XxvAax5OABKUBpjPzgSCAJZ0AAXhE3GLC4zQyXZYrXnX+4yW4zAF9gvOC17IBUR5wuzO59vFwFj4e0G3IKeSheL4oMgUMhkgYJYABEACFZwbHFMSApNvkELtkjg74cy7XccwQsgZ1XAA+McJzMKcsOTABtABdYt-2SLgOwaLweVQSDHxzSDoPnJxUHxLxn23FDoHg5MChxOj6kaZDULIdDMIeZNcII6tayfGCXzRZsaHYYS11AMjOF1OTvi7ABGfgQOgc0p34fSJEM7sACZ+FbdhICnKjVJfLieNALTEICASgMkwTvinH8Fwvec-2CJsWzhaQdKYljQtjRpYvfYR124aR-Kk7CkNo8xxIfWTsJUzirW83c33vajkpS5sJwCaB4GYLt0tCoA)

Comment: `this` does not make any sense there - a `.filter`'s callback doesn't get called with any sensible `this`. Use the argument instead. The first argument in a `.filter` callback is the item being iterated over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the keyword this

```
class User {
    id: number;
    admin: boolean;

    constructor(id: number, admin: boolean) {
        this.id = id;
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    becomeAdmin() {
        this.admin = true;
    }
}

interface DB {
    filterUsers(filter: (user: User) => boolean): User[];
}

function getDB(): DB {
    return {
        filterUsers: function(filter: (user: User) => boolean) {
            const users = [new User(1, false), new User(2, true)];
            return users.filter(filter);
        }
    }
}

const db = getDB();
const admins = db.filterUsers(function(user: User) {
    return user.admin;
});

console.log(admins);
```

[working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBYIqHDNDxkLyIeB9BjA9g0L5uMzMdgMZiQfiwaDqRJM%20B6EReABEAFFVgxEAt9OKktjxeAHKgAOTCABykAk4qCKgA8l8yO9BLytJAjqhHApXNI8KAnPSdMMsPoUAhENDhJc2RIGdERAYONiFkxWBweEFFPyGIJhPdzdiAN6KEolCjcfL9diIaTfADc6YzDG4iAyOeB8BanGLJZKCE4glQZHYsHQZAAFFmc5w8wWyBdy5XxvAax5OABKUBpjPzgSCAJZ0AAXhE3GLC4zQyXZYrXnX%204yW4zAF9gvOC17IBUR5wuzO59vFwFj4e0G3IKeSheL4oMgUMhkgYJYABEACFZwbHFMSApNvkELtkjg74cy7dhkxzBCyBnVcAD4xwnMwp2w5MAG0AF1i3-ZIuA7BovB5VBIMfHNIOg%20cnFQfEvGfbcUOgeDkwKHF6PqRpkNQsh0MwtCHmTPDCOrWsnxgl80WbGg5J%20NdQHIzhdQU74uwARn4EDoHNKd%20EMiRjO7AAmfhW3YSAp2o9SX243jQB0pdBKAqShO%20KcfwXC95z-YImxbOFpD05jWLC2NGji99hHXbhpACQLvhwpC6PMCSHx0sjQs4jMfNpPzkzfe8aJS1LmwnAJoHgZguwysKgA)